# CoreData Sort By NSDate not work?

Tags: core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

In Code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)getFetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"LatestNews"];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"News" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    [request setFetchLimit:kDefaultNewsLimit];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:20];
    [request setIncludesSubentities:NO];
    [request setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *dateSortor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateAdded" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dateSortor]];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"LatestNews"];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (isFirstLoading) {
        [refreshView refreshLastUpdatedDate];
        NSError *error;
        if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
            if ([error code]) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        loadMoreButton.hidden = self.numberOfLimitedNews > 0 ? NO : YES;
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -70) animated:YES];

        [refreshView setState:EGOOPullRefreshLoading];
        isRefreshing = YES;;
        [self performSelector:@selector(fetchNewsFromInternet) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
        isFirstLoading = NO;
    }
}
```

The results:

```
2011-09-13 16:48:20.959 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-02-04 06:00:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:21.079 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-09-13 08:29:48 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:21.230 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-02-19 01:30:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:21.463 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-09-13 08:45:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:21.879 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-03-06 02:00:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:22.143 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2010-12-01 02:40:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:22.229 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-09-13 02:03:43 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:22.313 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-09-13 08:10:33 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:22.446 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-01-02 06:00:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:22.627 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-09-13 08:45:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:22.978 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-01-23 02:00:01 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:23.092 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-09-13 03:35:40 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:23.196 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-02-18 06:20:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:23.346 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-09-13 00:00:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:23.812 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-02-08 06:00:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:23.980 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-09-12 01:40:10 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:24.179 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-01-18 06:00:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:26.257 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2010-12-22 06:30:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:27.783 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-02-08 06:00:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:27.784 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-09-12 01:40:10 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:27.785 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-01-18 06:00:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:27.785 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2010-12-22 06:30:00 +0000
2011-09-13 16:48:27.786 HJNews[5971:bc03] 2011-09-13 02:10:17 +0000
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, I seems sort by shuffle... anyone help me?

**It's normal when first loading, but abnormal when tap load more button or change the ([category navigation bar](http://www.firestudio.cn/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/2011-09-15-10.39.57.png))**

Comment: What is dateAdded? Is it an NSDate?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's news added in the server database time.

Comment: Mmmm. Could you show us the code that takes the fetch results and writes out the diagnostics above please?

Comment: try removing the cache. Set the cache name to nil.

Comment: I removed the cache, but the problem not resolved...

Comment: it looks like a bug somewhere in apple, in my case, if i dont use the IN, than the sorting works, but somehow, using the IN in predicate makes it work wrong

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you have your attribute type for `dateAdded` set to `Date` in your data model and `NSDate` in your class file.

Comment: Yes, I checked, they are NSDate type ;-(

Comment: Check that your output is not from an `NSSet` (which is not ordered), but an `NSArray` (which is).

Comment: I looked for NSFetchedResultsController's fetchedObjects type, it's _PFMutableProxyArray, but when I changed the predicate(clicked at the top of the navigation category, see the [image](http://www.firestudio.cn/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/2011-09-15-10.39.57.png)) it changes to _PFArray

Comment: **It's normal when first loading, but abnormal when tap load more button or change the (category navigation bar)**